# How do I combine variables in php

Tags: php

I am trying to create the following:

```
 $w1 = car; $w2 = train; $w3 = boat;
```

I would like to be able to build the variable `$w2`. The number 2 comes from a user input. 
Number 2 is stored in a variable called $a

So if `$a` stores the value 2, how do I echo out the word "train"?
The following would echo "2"

```
<?php
   echo $w$a
?>
```

Comment: Concatenation operator -- `.`

Comment: echo $w1 . $w2 . $w3 Concatenate them using "." (dot)

Comment: $w{$a} does not work.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
<?php 
$w = 'derp';
$a = 2;

$derp2 = 'u wot m8?';

echo ${$w.$a};
?>
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/170785)

---

Note how we initialise `$w`? You'll need that to point to the variables.

Alternatively, you could do as `xd6_` stated below and point directly to `$wNUMBER` with the following snippet of code:

```
${'w'.$a};
```

Comment: I think he wants ${'w'.$a} here though

Comment: @xd6_ You have a great point there. Just wrote the answer in terms of expansion so that he can change variable names if he wants :P

Comment: Your example works. My second variable in real life is actually $_GET[site] and with that variable your example does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Sandor and what does `$_GET['site']` hold? (Well what relevance does it have to this issue?)

Comment: @xd6_ you are absolutely right. It works fine now! And my thoughts are with the guy who down voted my question.

Comment: @Darren it holds a number, I just thought that it is relevant, but now it is not. xd6_ gave the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be using an array.

```
$w = array('car', 'train', 'boat');
```

In which case you can use

```
echo $w[$a-1]; // Array elements usually start at 0, so element 1 is the second element
```

Note that the syntax for your original code is wrong - you should wrap your strings in quotes

```
$w1 = 'car';
```